# SAS using PRX to find string pattern

Tags: regex, sas

I have a SAS dataset with multiple observations containing text from a PDF in a single variable.

I need to parse string with following pattern for further processing.

```
txt="ABCCXX.DEFG hijkj LMNO = YYYYYYYY"
```

- XX can be any character from A-Z (uppercase) (total 2 characters, always)
- YYYYYYYY can be any character from A-Z (uppercase) or any digit from 0 to 9 (maximum 8 characters, including digits if present; but can be less than 8)
- Other characters mentioned are always same (i.e. first char is always A, 2nd always B, so on).
- There is always a white space after the string ends (maybe it helps search).
- There can be multiple occurrences of this string. I need each occurrence in a separate variable

With my limited knowledge of PRX functions I was able to come up with following only. Obviously, it doesn't handle 'b' and 'e' I mentioned above.

```
data want;
   set have;
   length var8 $200;
   search8 = prxparse("/[A][B][C][C][A-Z][A-Z][.][D][E][F][G][\s][h][i][j][k][j][\s][L][M][N][O][\s][=][\s][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/oi");
   if prxmatch(search8,txt) then do;
     call prxsubstr(search8,txt,start,length);
     if start>0 then var8=substr(txt,start,length);
   end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `[]` character class when only one character.

You will want a pattern with `()` capture groups for extraction and `{a,b}` for occurrence range. The pattern can be applied multiple times via `PRXNEXT` in a loop.

Example:

```
data work.have;
  length line $256;
  input;
  line = _infile_;
datalines4;
txt="ABCCPQ.DEFG hijkj LMNO = 123456AB"
txt="ABCCVW.DEFG hijkj LMNO = ZZZZZZZZ"; txt="ABCCXY.DEFG hijkj LMNO = 12"
;;;;

data want;
  rx = prxparse('m/"ABCC([A-Z]{2})\.DEFG hijkj LMNO = ([A-Z0-9]{1,8})"/');

  set work.have;

  length found $256;

  start = 1;
  stop = length(line);
  do index = 1 by 1;
    call prxnext(rx, start, stop, line, pos, length);
    if pos = 0 then leave;
    found = substr(line, pos, length);
    xx = prxposn(rx,1,line);
    yy = prxposn(rx,2,line);
    put pos= found= xx= yy=;
  end;
run;
```

Will log

```
pos=5 found="ABCCPQ.DEFG hijkj LMNO = 123456AB" xx=PQ yy=123456AB
pos=5 found="ABCCVW.DEFG hijkj LMNO = ZZZZZZZZ" xx=VW yy=ZZZZZZZZ
pos=46 found="ABCCXY.DEFG hijkj LMNO = 12" xx=XY yy=12
```